# Protocol buffer failed to parse single codeInputStream having multiple large size of message

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

Here is the message schema:>

```
message ServerResponse {
optional string ReferenceCode = 1;
optional NestedMessageProto.NestedMessage NestedMessage = 2;//Huge size data in response
optional bool Success = 3 [default = false];
repeated Errors Errors = 4;
}
```

Below is code for getting the response from serve and calling the proto response method.

```
 String apiResponse = Server Response
    protoResponseClass.parseFrom(apiResponse.getBytes())

its failing when reading the NestedMessage  response on below bold line

    public int pushLimit(int byteLimit) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
    if (byteLimit < 0) {
        throw InvalidProtocolBufferException.negativeSize();
    }
    byteLimit += totalBytesRetired + bufferPos;
    if (byteLimit > currentLimit) {
        currentLimit = byteLimit + currentLimit;
    }
    final int oldLimit = currentLimit;
    **if (byteLimit > oldLimit) {
        throw InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage();
    }**
    currentLimit = byteLimit;
    recomputeBufferSizeAfterLimit();
    return oldLimit;
}
```

When its reading nested message the byte limit becoming greater than old limit.
What could be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts. Your code is really hard to read at the moment, due to a lack of indentation and random blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting httpresponse to string and then to byte array for parsing, use EntityUtils.toByteArray directly.

```
private String readResponse(HttpResponse httpresponse) throws IOException {
        int responseCode = httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String mimeType = httpresponse.getFirstHeader(CONTENT_TYPE_KEY).getValue();
        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String cause = String.format("Bad HTTP response code: %d\nOr MIME type: %s", responseCode, mimeType);
            throw new IOException(cause);
        }
        return EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly the problem:

```
String apiResponse = Server Response
protoResponseClass.parseFrom(apiResponse.getBytes())
```

Protocol buffer messages are *binary* data. They're not text, and shouldn't be handled as text. You're taking the binary response from the server, interpreting it as text in some way (we can't tell how), then converting it back to a byte array using the platform default encoding (which is almost always a bad idea - never call `getBytes()` without specifying a charset, even when calling `getBytes()` *is* appropriate, which it's not here). The conversion to text and back is almost certainly losing information - quite possibly making the parsing code expect more data than is actually present in the message.

You should be handling the server response as binary data from the start - ideally just passing an `InputStream` from the server response into `parseFrom`, but *at least* reading it as a byte array instead of a `String`.